# My grid won't place elements in the middle

Tags: html, sass

First post here, feel free to tell me if I missed something (like presentation type or else)

I'm a dev in training, I had my first site to do after 1 week, I failed, I'm training this week to do it right, but no matter how hard I try, it seems I can't get my grid to place in the center of my page, I did put the same padding I put on the rest of my page, I tried with `flexbox` instead but made it worse...

I'll show you my code, please tell me or give me a hint of what I'm doing wrong.

```
<main>

    <!-- Banniere Top -->
    <header>
        <img src="img/header-page-catalogue.png" alt="box">
    </header>
    <!-- Banniere Top -->

    <section>
        <article>
            <div>
                <img src="img/gant-boxe-1.png" alt="boxx">
                <p>NTS DE BOXE COMBAT KONTACT</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">VOIR LE PRIX</a>
                <p>125€ 60€</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div>
                <img src="img/gant-boxe-1.png" alt="boxx">
                <p>NTS DE BOXE COMBAT KONTACT</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">VOIR LE PRIX</a>
                <p>125€ 60€</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div>
                <img src="img/gant-boxe-1.png" alt="boxx">
                <p>NTS DE BOXE COMBAT KONTACT</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">VOIR LE PRIX</a>
                <p>125€ 60€</p>
            </div>
        </article>
        <article>
            <div>
                <img src="img/gant-boxe-1.png" alt="boxx">
                <p>NTS DE BOXE COMBAT KONTACT</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#">VOIR LE PRIX</a>
                <p>125€ 60€</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>
```

And here is my SCSS:

```
body{
    font-size: 14px;
    header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 100%;
        padding-left: 17%;
        padding-right: 17%;
        padding-top: 2%;
        section{
            display: inline-block;
            align-self: flex-end;
        }
        nav{
            div{
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
                margin: 10px;
                margin-right: 0;
                padding: 10px 50px;
                border: 1px;
                border-style: solid;
                background-color: lightgrey;
                img{
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }
            }
            p{
                text-align: end;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                margin-top: 0;
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
            li{
                list-style: none;
                display: inline;
                margin-right: 15px;
                a{
                    text-decoration: none;
                    &:first-child{
                        padding-right: 30px;
                    }
                    &:last-child{
                        padding-left: 30px;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

span{
    color: yellow;
}

main{
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    padding-left: 17%;
    padding-right: 17%;
    header{
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
    section{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: 400px 225px;
        grid-template-rows: 500px 200px;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

This is supposed to look something like this (the 4 square with boxing gloves):

---

Thanks for reading, hope I was clear enough, hope I'll help someone later when I have the knowledge!

( sorry i have to remove the pics cause they're still used for exam at my school. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
article {
    margin: auto;
}
```

This will automatically center these elements within each grid-cell.

Comment: What else are you after?

Comment: It's because your columns aren't equal values: `grid-template-columns: 400px 225px;`. The left column is bigger than the right.

Comment: Thank you so much, it put the value auto and deleted the line with justify-content and it's now centered. How can i put my post in "answered mode" ? :)